# Building Android applications with JBuilder?

Tags: java, android, jbuilder

- Is it possible, and how to build Android applications from JBuilder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On their website, Android support is not mentioned, but since it is build on Eclipse, you should be able to install the [ADT-Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing) from Google.

Comment: Just follow the instructions on the linked page, they should be the same for JBuilder.

Comment: thank you very much. I am trying but somethings are not yet clear for me as a beginner in this direction. I hope the upcomming version of JBuilder to support Android development complete.